# Single word meaning "reverse delegation"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word which means "reverse delegation" or "upwards delegation", which is a person passing work upwards to the highest level that will accept it?

This question has also been raised [here](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/39640-upwards-reverse-delegation.html), but no acceptable answer was given.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In IT and customer services, when a level one/lower level support technician cannot help with a query, they **escalate** it to a level 2 or even higher level support technician.

This is not a widely used term, and I could not find a definition related to this; but it could work depending on your context.

Comment: Escalation is perfectly understandable to me and we use it often when, as in your example, a customer support issue needs to be passed up to a higher level of technical support.